# Deep combine NSDictionaries

Tags: objective-c, merge, nsdictionary

I need to merge two `NSDictionary`s into one provided that if there are dictionaries within the dictionaries, they are also merged.

More or less like jQuery's [`extend`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.extend/) function.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

NSDictionary+Merge.h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface NSDictionary (Merge)

+ (NSDictionary *) dictionaryByMerging: (NSDictionary *) dict1 with: (NSDictionary *) dict2;
- (NSDictionary *) dictionaryByMergingWith: (NSDictionary *) dict;

@end
```

---

NSDictionary+Merge.m

```
#import "NSDictionary+Merge.h"

@implementation NSDictionary (Merge)

+ (NSDictionary *) dictionaryByMerging: (NSDictionary *) dict1 with: (NSDictionary *) dict2 {
    NSMutableDictionary * result = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithDictionary:dict1];

[dict2 enumerateKeysAndObjectsUsingBlock: ^(id key, id obj, BOOL *stop) {
    if (![dict1 objectForKey:key]) {
        if ([obj isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]]) {
            NSDictionary * newVal = [[dict1 objectForKey: key] dictionaryByMergingWith: (NSDictionary *) obj];
            [result setObject: newVal forKey: key];
        } else {
            [result setObject: obj forKey: key];
        }
    }
}];

    return (NSDictionary *) [[result mutableCopy] autorelease];
}
- (NSDictionary *) dictionaryByMergingWith: (NSDictionary *) dict {
    return [[self class] dictionaryByMerging: self with: dict];
}

@end
```

Comment: So, if I am reading this correctly, the logic in that enumeration block is "If `dict1` does not contain an object for `key` and `dict2`'s object for `key` is a dictionary, then merge `dict1`'s object for `key` into `dict2`'s object for `key`"... but we already know that `dict1` does not have an object for that `key`. So all that the block is doing is adding any objects from `dict2` that are not already in `dict1` into `dict1`.

Comment: I think your first check in the enumeration is incorrect and should be removed. `if (![dict1 objectForKey:key])` makes it so any keys that are in `dict2` but not in dict1 will not be written. Maybe that is by design, but if you want to add any unique keys from `dict2` you should not include this check.

Answer (score 7):

I think this is what you're looking for:

First, you need to make a **deep mutable copy**, so you can create a category on `NSDictionary` to do this:

```
@implementation NSDictionary (DeepCopy)

- (id)deepMutableCopy
{
    id copy(id obj) {
        id temp = [obj mutableCopy];
        if ([temp isKindOfClass:[NSArray class]]) {
            for (int i = 0 ; i < [temp count]; i++) {
               id copied = [copy([temp objectAtIndex:i]) autorelease];
               [temp replaceObjectAtIndex:i withObject:copied];
            }
        } else if ([temp isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]]) {
            NSEnumerator *enumerator = [temp keyEnumerator];
            NSString *nextKey;
            while (nextKey = [enumerator nextObject])
                [temp setObject:[copy([temp objectForKey:nextKey]) autorelease]
                         forKey:nextKey];
        } 
        return temp;
    }

    return (copy(self));
}

@end
```

Then, you can call `deepMutableCopy` like this:

```
NSMutableDictionary *someDictionary = [someDict deepMutableCopy];
[someDictionary addEntriesFromDictionary:otherDictionary];
```

Comment: And this is recursive? In that NSDictionaries in the NSDictionaries will also be merged?

Comment: I think we should also replace "return temp;" with "return [temp autorelease];"   and replace " return (copy(self));" with " return [(copy(self)) retain];"   to avoid leaks

Comment: @someone0 `-mutableCopy` is implied to return ownership back to the callee. Therefore, we do not autorelease the return value.

Comment: @Jacob Relkin  yes, but I think there is a problem when inserting a copied object using setObject:forKey:  
It will be copied then retained. In this case I will add autorelease for objects inserted using replaceObjectAtIndex: and setObject:forKey:

Comment: @JacobRelkin another detail: To have compiling code  "id copy(id obj)" definition should be outside  "- (id)deepMutableCopy" implementation.

Answer (score 4):

I added this to the code mentioned above.  It may not be fully correct, but it handles the case where 2 dict has an element that 1 dict does not.

```
+ (NSDictionary *) dictionaryByMerging: (NSDictionary *) dict1 with: (NSDictionary *) dict2 {
    NSMutableDictionary * result = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithDictionary:dict1];
    NSMutableDictionary * resultTemp = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithDictionary:dict1];

    [resultTemp addEntriesFromDictionary:dict2];

    [resultTemp enumerateKeysAndObjectsUsingBlock: ^(id key, id obj, BOOL *stop) {
    if ([dict1 objectForKey:key]) {
        if ([obj isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]]) {
            NSDictionary * newVal = [[dict1 objectForKey: key] dictionaryByMergingWith: (NSDictionary *) obj];
            [result setObject: newVal forKey: key];
        } else {
            [result setObject: obj forKey: key];
        }
    }
    else if([dict2 objectForKey:key])
    {
        if ([obj isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]]) {
            NSDictionary * newVal = [[dict2 objectForKey: key] dictionaryByMergingWith: (NSDictionary *) obj];
            [result setObject: newVal forKey: key];
        } else {
            [result setObject: obj forKey: key];
        }
    }
}];

return (NSDictionary *) [[result mutableCopy] autorelease];
```

}

Answer (score 1):

I came here looking for a copy of jQuery's `extend` but I ended up writing my own implementation. It's a super simple implementation, I did it so I'd understand a way to do it.

```
+(NSDictionary*) dictionaryByExtending:(NSDictionary*)baseDictionary WithDictionary:(NSDictionary*)extensionDictionary {

    NSMutableDictionary * resultDictionary = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithDictionary:baseDictionary];

    [extensionDictionary enumerateKeysAndObjectsUsingBlock:^(id key, id obj, BOOL *stop) {

        BOOL isDict = [obj isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]];
        BOOL hasValue = [baseDictionary hasObjectForKey:key] != nil;

        id setObj = obj;

        if( hasValue && isDict ) {

            BOOL hasDict = [[baseDictionary objectForKey:key] isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]];

            if( hasDict ) {

                NSDictionary * extendedChildDictionary = [NSDictionary dictionaryByExtending:[baseDictionary objectForKey:key] WithDictionary:obj];
                setObj = extendedChildDictionary;

            }

        }

        [resultDictionary setObject:setObj forKey:key];

    }];

    return resultDictionary;

}

-(NSDictionary*) dictionaryByExtendingWithDictionary:(NSDictionary*)extensionDictionary {
    return [NSDictionary dictionaryByExtending:self WithDictionary:extensionDictionary];
}
```

Hopefully someone will find this helpful, it worked in my tests with deep-recursion. I'm using it to extend deep JSON files full of text.

Comment: Minor change: `BOOL hasValue = [baseDictionary objectForKey:key] != nil;`  Otherwise, works well.

Answer (score 1):

Alexsander Akers works for me except the case where dict2 contains a dictionary that's missing from dict1 - it crashes.  I changed the logic to this:

```
+ (NSDictionary *) dictionaryByMerging: (NSDictionary *) dict1 with: (NSDictionary *) dict2 {
    NSMutableDictionary * result = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithDictionary:dict1];

    [dict2 enumerateKeysAndObjectsUsingBlock: ^(id key, id obj, BOOL *stop) {
        if (![dict1 objectForKey:key]) {
            [result setObject: obj forKey: key];
        } else if ([obj isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]]) {
            NSDictionary * newVal = [[dict1 objectForKey: key] dictionaryByMergingWith: (NSDictionary *) obj];
            [result setObject: newVal forKey: key];
        }
    }];

    return (NSDictionary *) [result mutableCopy];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question, but I need to do the same thing: recursively merge two dictionary objects. I need to go a step further and merge any objects that can be merged recursively (the end goal is merging two dictionaries created from plists). I am hosting my solution at https://github.com/bumboarder6/NSDictionary-merge

I am still working on the project, but as of this writing it already works (in limited testing) for recursive dictionary merging. Arrays and Sets are coming soon.

I noticed a few logic errors in some other solutions I have seen for this problem and I hopefully avoided those pitfalls, but critiques are welcome.

Usage is simple:

```
#import "NSMutableDictionary-merge.h"

NSMutableDictionary* dict1 = [NSMutableDictionary ...];
NSDictionary* dict2 = [NSDictionary ...];

[dict1 mergeWithDictionary:dict2];
```

Comment: My apologies, I was interrupted while reading and, it seems, I didn't actually finish before commenting.

Comment: No worries. I'm going to go ahead and delete this little interaction -- not exactly relevant in the end :)

Answer (score 0):

```
#import "NSDictionary+Merge.h"

@implementation NSDictionary (Merge)

+ (NSDictionary *)dictionaryByMerging:(NSDictionary *)src with:(NSDictionary *)new
{
    NSMutableDictionary *result = [src mutableCopy];
    [new enumerateKeysAndObjectsUsingBlock:^(id key, id obj, BOOL *stop) {
        if ([obj isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]]
            && [src[key] isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]]) {

            result[key] = [src[key] dictionaryByMergingWith:obj];
        } else {
            result[key] = obj;
        }
    }];
    return [NSDictionary dictionaryWithDictionary:result];
}

- (NSDictionary *)dictionaryByMergingWith:(NSDictionary *)dict {
    return [[self class] dictionaryByMerging:self with:dict];
}

@end
```

Answer (score 0):

I needed a way to recursively merge (append) objects within two JSON objects, focusing on the NSDictionaries within, but also considering NSArrays, and gracefully handling when types don't match along the way.  The other answers here didn't go that far, and so I needed to write it myself.  The following handles all those cases.  Because the validation is at the top rather than in the middle it is usable starting with mixed nonnull and nullable objects.  It could be expanded in the future to support additional types where appending may apply.  To use, rename the xxx_ prefix to your own three digit prefix in lowercase.  This is appropriate since this is an extension to a foundation class:

NSObject+Append.h

```
@interface NSObject (Append)

+ (nullable id)xxx_objectAppendingObject1:(nullable id)object1 object2:(nullable id)object2 NS_SWIFT_NAME(kva_objectAppending(object1:object2:));


@end
```

NSObject+Append.m

```
@implementation NSObject (Append)


+ (nullable id)xxx_objectAppendingObject1:(nullable id)object1 object2:(nullable id)object2
{
    // VALIDATE ELSE RETURN
    if (object1 == nil)
    {
        return object2;
    }

    if (object2 == nil)
    {
        return object1;
    }

    // MAIN
    // dictionary1
    NSDictionary *dictionary1 = [object1 isKindOfClass:NSDictionary.class] ? (NSDictionary *)object1 : nil;
    
    // dictionary2
    NSDictionary *dictionary2 = [object2 isKindOfClass:NSDictionary.class] ? (NSDictionary *)object2 : nil;
    
    // array1
    NSArray *array1 = [object1 isKindOfClass:NSArray.class] ? (NSArray *)object1 : nil;
    
    // array2
    NSArray *array2 = [object2 isKindOfClass:NSArray.class] ? (NSArray *)object2 : nil;
    
    // A. NSDICTIONARY TO NSDICTIONARY
    if ((dictionary1 != nil) && (dictionary2 != nil))
    {
        NSMutableDictionary *returnDictionary = dictionary1.mutableCopy;
        [dictionary2 enumerateKeysAndObjectsUsingBlock: ^(id key, id obj, BOOL *stop)
        {
            returnDictionary[key] = [self.class kva_objectAppendingObject1:dictionary1[key] object2:obj];
        }];
        return returnDictionary;
    }

    // B. NSARRAY TO NSARRAY
    if ((array1 != nil) && (array2 != nil))
    {
        return [array1.mutableCopy arrayByAddingObjectsFromArray:array2];
    }

    // DEFAULT
    return object2;
}

@end
```

Comment: I don't like the category on NSObject. It takes too much responsibility of every kind of object in Cocoa, while the original intention is only for Collections, and if I'm not mistaken - not even all of these, just NSDictionaries and NSArrays. Also merging is not merely appending... what about removals and value changes?