# Merge two NSDIctionay in one NSDictonary

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, ios4, nsdictionary

I want to merge two NSDictionary in one NSDictionary. 
my first DIctionary

```
BreakFast Dates Dic {
    "2012-07-24" = "27";
    "2012-08-03" = "98";
    "2012-08-06" = "4203";
    "2012-08-23" = "0";
    "2012-08-24" = "0";
    "2012-09-11" = "36";
    "2012-09-19" = "450";
    "2012-09-24" = "36";
    Goals = 3;
}
```

my second Dictonary

```
Dinner Dates Dic {
    "2012-08-03" = "100";
    "2012-08-27" = "0";
    "2012-09-19" = "270";
    Goals = 4;
}
```

i want to merge both dictionary into one. like if in breakfast i have "2012-09-19" and same date i have in dinner. i want to separate both values by comma (,) .
my resultant dictionary should be like this.

```
combine {
    "2012-07-24" = "27,0";
    "2012-08-03" = "98,100";
    "2012-08-06" = "4203,0";
    "2012-08-23" = "0,0";
    "2012-08-24" = "0,0";
    "2012-09-11" = "36,0";
    "2012-09-19" = "450,270";
    "2012-09-24" = "36,0";
    Goals = 3,4;
}
```

Comment: if have to do that iterating on on dictionary... there is no other way...

Comment: It can be done but any processing on the combined structure will be more difficult than the separate info - why do you need this? Also do you want the combined info to be one string or what is `"36",0` ?

Comment: it can be one string. i will split it afterwards by comma(,), i want to plot graph. from one Dictionary like 98 will be of red color and 100 will be of blue. that how i want it to work.

Comment: What if one date is not in both dictionaries ? How the combined entry will look like ?

Comment: it will give 0... like in dinner 2012-9-24 is not present then in combine its 0 there on 2012-09-24 .. "36,0"

Comment: Here are a good answer that could help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4011781/deep-combine-nsdictionaries

Comment: Why are you keeping the values as strings with digits instead of just storing NSNumber instances?

Comment: Sometimes you have to actually write some code.  Have you thought about how you might write it?  Have you tried anything?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
NSMutableDictionary *combined = [objectDelegate.dataBreakFastSummary mutableCopy];
    for(NSString *key in [combined allKeys])
    {
        NSString *breakfastDate = [objectDelegate.dataBreakFastSummary valueForKey:key];
        NSString *dinnerDate = [objectDelegate.dataDinnerSummary objectForKey:key];
        if(dinnerDate){
            [combined setObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@,%@",breakfastDate, dinnerDate] forKey:key];
            } else {
                [combined setObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@,0",breakfastDate] forKey:key];
                }
    }
    NSLog(@"Combine %@",combined);
```