# how to add to existing Nsmutabledictionary?

Tags: iphone, ios, nsmutabledictionary

Hello everyone i have a mutable Nsdcitionary. I have a function where it sets the Nsdcitionary  content using this dict = [json mutableCopy];. Now i am trying to re call the function but i need to retain the old values. How to do that?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4011781/deep-combine-nsdictionaries

Comment: save the value in another dict, and after returning from the method, set all the values again

Answer (score 0):

i suppose this could help

```
[dict1 addEntriesFromDictionary:dict2];
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
NSMutableDictionary *dict1=[[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
[dict1 setObject:@"ravi" forKey:@"Name"];

NSMutableDictionary *dict2=[[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
[dict2 setObject:@"22" forKey:@"Age"];

[dict1 addEntriesFromDictionary:dict2];

NSLog(@"%@",dict1);
//it will print 

//    Age = 22;
 //   Name = ravi;
```