# NSMutableDictionary addEntriesFromDictionary not merging dictionaries properly

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, nsdictionary, nsmutabledictionary

I have a JSON response that I store as an NSMutableDictionary that looks like this:

```
    {
        "list": { "ID1", "ID2", "ID3" },

        "items": {
            "ID1" : { "name" : "shoe" },
            "ID2" : { "name" : "pants" },
            "ID3" : { "name" : "hat" }
        }
    }
```

i need to have the NSMutableDictionary add entries from any additional JSON responses, so if i receive a new response as follows:

```
{
    "list": { "ID4", "ID5", "ID6" },

    "items": {
        "ID4" : { "name" : "shirt" },
        "ID5" : { "name" : "tie" },
        "ID6" : { "name" : "glasses" }
    }
}
```

the updated NSMutableDictionary needs to appear as follows:

```
    {
        "list": { "ID1", "ID2", "ID3", "ID4", "ID5", "ID6" },

        "items": {
            "ID1" : { "name" : "shoe" },
            "ID2" : { "name" : "pants" },
            "ID3" : { "name" : "hat" },
            "ID4" : { "name" : "shirt" },
            "ID5" : { "name" : "tie" },
            "ID6" : { "name" : "glasses" }
        }
    }
```

Unfortunately, when i call `addEntriesFromDictionary` with the additions, i get this:

```
{
            "list": { "ID1", "ID2", "ID3" },

            "items": {
                "ID1" : { "name" : "shoe" },
                "ID2" : { "name" : "pants" },
                "ID3" : { "name" : "hat" }
            }
        }
             "list": { "ID4", "ID5", "ID6" },

             "items": {
                 "ID4" : { "name" : "shirt" },
                 "ID5" : { "name" : "tie" },
                 "ID6" : { "name" : "glasses" }
           }
    }
```

Comment: I think what you need to do is what is called "deep merge", this may help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4011781/deep-combine-nsdictionaries

Comment: I would suggest that you create a class that represents your data with appropriate initialisers and functions to accept dictionaries rather than relying on the dictionary structure directly

Answer (score 0):

Assuming we have the same dictionaries as in your example:

```
let key1 = "list"
let key2 = "items"

var rec = [key1:["ID1","ID2","ID3"],
           key2:["ID1":["name":"shoe"],"ID2":["name":"pants"],"ID3":["name":"hat"]]] as [String : Any]
let inc = [key1:["ID4","ID5","ID6"],
           key2:["ID4":["name":"shirt"],"ID5":["name":"tie"],"ID6":["name":"glasses"]]] as [String : Any]
```

I used the following rationale to find a solution:
[image]

... implemented this code snippet hereafter:

```
func merge(_ inc:[String:Any], into rec: inout [String:Any]) -> [String:Any] {
    for (_, vals) in inc {
        if var recKeys = rec[key1] as? [String],
            var recItems = rec[key2] as? [String:[String:String]],
            let incItems = inc[key2] as? [String:[String:String]] {

            if let incValIds = vals as? [String] {
                for id in incValIds {
                    if let newVal = incItems[id] {
                        if recKeys.contains(id) {
                            for (newValId, newValObj) in newVal {
                                guard var tab = recItems[id] else { continue }
                                tab[newValId] = newValObj
                                recItems[id] = tab
                            }
                        } else {
                            recKeys.append(id)
                            recItems[id] = newVal
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            rec[key1] = recKeys
            rec[key2] = recItems
        }
    }
    return rec
}
```

... and used this function as described hereunder to get the result defined below:

```
let updatedInfo = merge(inc, into: &rec)
print(updatedInfo)
```

[image]

You can now **properly merge the two provided dictionaries** as desired.