# Update NSMutableDictionary but keep existing keys and values

Tags: objective-c, dictionary, nsdictionary, xcode8

*I am on Objective-C, Xcode 8, OSX, not iOS.*
I have an instance of NSMutableDictionary like this (written by hand to explain case, untested)

```
NSMutableDictionary* oldDict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:
    @"Value 1",@"key1",
    @"Value 2",@"key2",
    @"Value 3",@"key3",
    nil]];
```

This dictionary changes its values based on user interaction and is saved on quit. On newer releases of the software, the dictionary will have more keys and values. like this:

```
NSMutableDictionary* newDict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:
    @"Value 1",@"key1",
    @"Value 2",@"key2",
    @"Value 3",@"key3",
    @"Value 4",@"key4",
    nil]];
```

When software is started, it loads the saved dictionary (which may be an old one) which i need to extend with the new key/value pairs but with keeping existing key/value pairs. In the above example only key/value pair nr. 4 should be added, nr. 1-3 shall be kept from existing dictionary to keep users values. Is there a more effective way than going through pair by pair?

Comment: Isn't `addEntriesFromDictionary` what you are looking for?

Comment: Apple Docs say: If both dictionaries contain the same key, the receiving dictionary’s previous value object for that key is sent a release message, and the new value object takes its place.

Comment: But I want to keep old values. Just want to add not existent key/value pairs

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4011781/deep-combine-nsdictionaries

Comment: Is there a particular reason why you can't check if the dictionary already contains that key before adding an element?

Comment: if your requirement is,   just want to keep the existing data on application start and add more values while you are working with the application.  Then the best idea is to use NSUserDefaults

Comment: @vadian 's suggestion is the correct way, the docs say that if there already is a `@"Value 4" key`, then it will be overriden. In your example there is no `@"Value 4"` in `oldDict`

Comment: Maybe just enumerate over all keys of new dictionary and see if old dictionary has them. Basically writing a custom merge method. 
Or call `addEntriesFromDictionary` on new dictionary so newer dictionary's values will be retained after merge

Comment: If you want to keep the old data call `addEntriesFromDictionary` on the new dictionary and add the old one.

Comment: That did the trick - just had to use it the other way around (Add the old to the new).